# How do I install the OCaml Core library on (Arch) Linux x86_64?

Tags: installation, ocaml, ocaml-core

```
$ ocaml -version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.1
$ opam --version
1.2.0
$ opam init 
$ opam install core

#=== ERROR while installing camlp4.4.02.1+system ==============================#
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           linux
# command      sh ./check-camlp4.sh
# path         /home/john/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    1
# env-file     /home/john/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-32324-f0f09f.env
# stdout-file  /home/john/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-32324-f0f09f.out
# stderr-file  /home/john/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-32324-f0f09f.err
### stdout ###
# ...[truncated]
# 4.02 by switching to a local installation via `opam switch 4.02.1`.
# 
# Here are some installation instructions for camlp4 if you obtained OCaml
# via the OPAM binary packages:
# 
# http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Aocaml&package=ocaml
# 
# * Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install camlp4-extra
# * RHEL/CentOS/Fedora: sudo yum install ocaml-camlp4
# 
### stderr ###
# ./check-camlp4.sh: line 3: camlp4orf: command not foun
```

I answered *yes* to the auto-complete scripts question during `opam init`. Also, the truncated portion of the error suggests the following:

> Please install a system-wide version of camlp4.  This is necessary
>   since you are using OCaml 4.02.1 and the system compiler switch (which
>   uses your preexisting installation rather than compile one from
>   scratch).
>
> If you cannot install a system-wide camlp4, then you can still use
>   OCaml
>   4.02 by switching to a local installation via `opam switch 4.02.1`

```
# pacman -S camlp4
$ opam install camlp4
$ opam info camlp4
            package: camlp4
            version: 4.02.1+system
         repository: default
           homepage: https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4
            license: LGPLv2
  installed-version: 4.02.1+system [system]
```

Once again...

```
$ opam install core

#=== ERROR while installing herelib.109.35.02 =================================#
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           linux
# command      make
# path         /home/john/.opam/system/build/herelib.109.35.02
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /home/john/.opam/system/build/herelib.109.35.02/herelib-31366-c61e7b.env
# stdout-file  /home/john/.opam/system/build/herelib.109.35.02/herelib-31366-c61e7b.out
# stderr-file  /home/john/.opam/system/build/herelib.109.35.02/herelib-31366-c61e7b.err
### stdout ###
# ...[truncated]
# ocamlfind ocamlopt -shared -linkall lib/herelib.cmxa -o lib/herelib.cmxs
# ocamlfind ocamldep -syntax camlp4o -package camlp4.extend -package camlp4.quotations -package camlp4.lib -modules lib/pa_here.mli > lib/pa_here.mli.depends
# ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -syntax camlp4o -package camlp4.extend -package camlp4.quotations -package camlp4.lib -I lib -o lib/pa_here.cmi lib/pa_here.mli
# + ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -syntax camlp4o -package camlp4.extend -package camlp4.quotations -package camlp4.lib -I lib -o lib/pa_here.cmi lib/pa_here.mli
# File "lib/pa_here.mli", line 1:
# Error: The files /usr/lib/ocaml/pervasives.cmi
#        and /usr/lib/ocaml/camlp4/Camlp4.cmi make inconsistent assumptions
#        over interface Pervasives
# Command exited with code 2.
# Makefile:21: recipe for target 'build' failed
### stderr ###
# File "setup.ml", line 232, characters 8-26:
# Warning 3: deprecated: String.set
# Use Bytes.set instead.
# File "setup.ml", line 2385, characters 6-24:
# Warning 3: deprecated: Lazy.lazy_from_fun
# Use Lazy.from_fun instead.
# E: Failure("Command ''/usr/bin/ocamlbuild' lib/herelib.cma lib/herelib.cmxa lib/herelib.a lib/herelib.cmxs lib/pa_herelib.cma lib/pa_herelib.cmxa lib/pa_here
lib.a lib/pa_herelib.cmxs -use-ocamlfind -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
# make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Do I need to switch to a different compiler?

```
$ opam switch
system  C system  System compiler (4.02.1)
--     -- 3.11.2  Official 3.11.2 release
--     -- 3.12.1  Official 3.12.1 release
--     -- 4.00.0  Official 4.00.0 release
--     -- 4.00.1  Official 4.00.1 release
--     -- 4.01.0  Official 4.01.0 release
--     -- 4.02.0  Official 4.02.0 release
--     -- 4.02.1  Official 4.02.1 release
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should switch from a system compiler to OPAM's one. Then the compiler's sources will be downloaded and compiled automatically as well as all prerequisites. In order to switch, use the following command:

```
opam switch 4.02.1
```

Instead of `4.02.1` you can use any available compiler of course.

The actual error is that for some reason (I think due to a rolling release model) you have different versions of `camlp4` and OCaml compiler, so that they can't talk to each other.

Comment: I noticed the camlp4 package is orphaned, which is unfortunate since it's in the official repository.

Comment: camlp4 is being deprecated as it's being replaced by ppx.

Comment: it is not deprecated, and is not replaced by ppx. ppx and camlp4 has some intersections, but they're completely different tools.